# Windows App Certification Kit error

Tags: windows, file-permissions

The kit started hanging for twenty minutes while testing an app, and I clicked cancel but it continued to hang. So I fired up task manager and killed it. Now it won't start at all due to error cleaning .etl file from the last session - no permission. It's in AppData/Local/Microsoft/AppCert/ftlog. Any suggestions?

No luck on Google search, and I've tried just deleting that file/folder. It's read only, and won't even show who owns it. The kit runs fine on the other accounts on my pc which have no ftlog folder since I haven't ran any sessions on those accounts. So I think getting rid of it would fix the problem. That's easier said than done however...

Also tried uninstalling/reinstalling Windows 10 sdk, but that didn't delete the AppData evidently.

Answer (score 0):

Rebooted this morning and problem solved! Hopefully this post can save someone an hour or two of your life.